# import com.gitlab.mvysny.jdbiorm.Dao fails for me

Tags: vaadin

I'm totally new to web development. I got interested in VaadinOnKotlin and I'm using the bookstore sample app as my template. I ran into an issue and I spent a long time googling for it but came up with zilch.

I'm trying to implement the following class, but it can't find com.gitlab.mvysny.jdbiorm.Dao

```
import com.github.vokorm.*
import com.gitlab.mvysny.jdbiorm.Dao

data class Article(
        override var id: Long? = null,

        var title: String? = null,

        var text: String? = null
) : KEntity<Long> {
    companion object : Dao<Article, Long>(Article::class.java)
```

what do I have to download in my build.gradle.kts to resolve this issue?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you added the library to your project? https://gitlab.com/mvysny/jdbi-orm

Comment: That's strange, jdbiorm should have been pulled in transitively and automatically by Gradle. Could you file a bug report into the project itself, into github/gitlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An import statement is only seeing libraries that you have already added to your project.

You mention using **gradle**. the [gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/jdbi-orm) of said library tells you to add the following lines to your gradle script:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()  // or mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile("com.gitlab.mvysny.jdbiorm:jdbi-orm:x.y")
}
```

If you were using **maven**, then you would include this dependency in your .pom file:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gitlab.mvysny.jdbiorm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi-orm</artifactId>
            <version>x.y</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You should now be able to import the class `com.gitlab.mvysny.jdbiorm.Dao`